# Are there rules about using magic outside of class?

Tags: harry-potter

While in Hogwarts and during the school year did students have rules about using magic outside of the classroom? For example, it could be dangerous to attempt new spells without teacher supervision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there were rules against using magic in the halls.  These rules were enforced by the teachers (who were usually busy getting ready for their next classes), by the Headmaster (who didn't make a point of wandering the halls), by the Prefects and Head Boy/Girl (Percy, for example, enjoyed telling the first years off for doing it), and by Filch (the Squib).

In other words, there were rules on the books.

These rules were, at best, selectively and weakly enforced.

Students were pretty much expected to do magic outside of their classrooms, but there were rules in place so the teachers could punish those who did so irresponsibly.

Comment: ... so the teachers *had an excuse to* punish those *they felt like punishing*.... Fixed that for you.

Comment: @DVK: Not all the teachers were Snape.  McGonnagal was actually fairly even-handed.

Comment: Gryffindors are very good at making you think they are doing the Right Thing. Witness Gazillion points they got for breaking school rules (and incidentally, fixing the major security lapse that Dumbdore committed) in PS

Comment: @DVK ... so the *moderators* had an excuse to *ban* those they felt like *banning*.... Fixed that for you.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

Dumbledore says this every year in his start of term speech:

> I have also been asked by Mr. Filch, the caretaker, to remind you all that no magic should be used between classes in the corridors.
> <sub>(*Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone - Chapter 7*)</sub>

Comment: @RedCaio - I have no idea how that came about. Feel free to retract your upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are rules about using magic outside of class. In addition to Dumbledore's announcement mentioned in [Ibid's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122716/100430), we actually find that Harry on occasion got reprimanded for this infraction. When he disarmed Malfoy in *Chamber of Secrets*  when Malfoy had picked up the diary, the following occurs:

> "Harry!" said Percy loudly. "No magic in the corridors. I'll have to report this, you know!"